# What is the function/method to open a .pdf file (in axAcroPDF...), which is stored in a folder and its file path is stored in a database?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Good day.

I have a Windows forms application (C#). 
With the "open file dialog" I can select a .pdf file.
Selected .pdf file is copied and stored in a pre-determined destination.
File path of selected .pdf file is stored in an SQL database.

**What is the function/method to open a .pdf file (in axAcroPDF...), which is stored in a folder and its file path is stored in a database?**

This is what I have, code vise:

```
            private void txtST1Cap_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SavedDocumentPath1 = @"XXX\";

            using (OpenFileDialog OpenFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog() { ValidateNames = true, Multiselect = false, Filter = "PDF|*.pdf" })

                if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    //display PDF in reader
                    OpenedDocument1 = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                    axAcroPDF1ST1.src = openFileDialog1.FileName;

                    //code for getting REF No. from opened file name
                    OpenedDocumentREF = Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                    REFfromOpenedDocument = OpenedDocumentREF.Substring(0, 12);
                    txtST1Cap.Text = REFfromOpenedDocument;

                    //destination of to-be saved document
                    SavedDocLoc1 = (SavedDocumentPath1 + Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName));
                    lblST1CapLocation.Text = SavedDocLoc1;
                }

        }
        private void btnST1Cap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            openFileDialog1.FileName=SavedDocLoc1;
            axAcroPDF1ST1.src = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
```

Button Clicl btnST1Cap does not work.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think what you have posted here would even compile. You have `OpenFileDialog1` and `openFileDialog1` in the same method. Do you have a member variable called `openFileDialog1`? You are then trying to use, in another method,  the variable (at least what I am guessing the code would read) that was locally defined in a using statement.  You need to store that value somewhere if you want to use it later (class variable, or as your answer shows, in a text box).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was almost correct.
So, if one wants to open a PDF document in a "default program" System.Diagnostics.Process,... is used:

```
          private void btnST1Cap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(lblST1CapLocation.Text);

       }
```

As mentioned, this opens a default .pdf browser.

I wanted, to open it in my form (in axAcroPDF...):

```
        private void btnST1Cap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axAcroPDF1ST1.src = lblST1CapLocation.Text;

        }
```

Yaaaay 4 ME!

In above cases "lblST1CapLocation.Text" is the label where file path is stored.
Direct file path can be inserted if wished:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\myPdf.pdf");
```